# Failed to convert a value of type java.util.HashMap to int

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code  for getting data from Firebase

```
  database?.getReference("tours")?.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("FirstFragment", "start")
            val list = ArrayList<Tours>()
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
      [enter image description here][1]          snapshot.children.forEach { it->
                    var tour = it.getValue(Tours::class.java)  //error is here!!
                    tour?.id = it.key
                    tour?.let {
                        list.add(tour)
                    }
                }
                Log.d("FirstFragment", list[0].companyName.toString())
                adapter?.setTours(list)
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.d("FirstFragment", error.toString())
        }

    })
```

It is an Tours class, and i get error herer //var tour = it.getValue(Tours::class.java)//

```
    package com.example.mainapplication

import java.io.Serializable


class Tours : Serializable{
    var id: String? = null
    var tourName: String?=null
    var description: String ?= null
    var imageId: String?=null
    var dateAndTime: String?=null
    var companyName: String?= null
    var price: Long?=null
    var regPeople: Int? = null
    var phone: String?=null
    var numbersOfPeople: Int?=null
    var bookedId: String? = null
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4UC5.jpg) [This is an error occurred]

What should i do to fix it?

[This is my Firebase for Tours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQaai.jpg)

Comment: Please paste the text of the error instead of an image.

Comment: Show `Tours` class and all 4 tours data in Firebase

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of your `Tours` class. Please respond with @AlexMamo